# Хранение данных в контексте приложения (java)

Tags: java, jsp, контекст

Мне нужно сохранять результаты функций и/или данные, полученные с формы на сайте, с помощью контекста приложения на языке Java. Я узнал об интерфейсе ApplicationContext, но не смог разобраться с его реализацией(

Comment: А зачем вам там данные хранить? Может их лучше хранить в сессии?

Comment: в ApplicationContext нужно хранить экземпляры компонентов и сервисов, а не заполненные формы. Заполненные формы лучше хранить в базе данных.

Comment: у  вас есть несколько уровней хранения формы для  передачи между  пользовательскими запросами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у  вас есть несколько уровней хранения формы для  передачи между  пользовательскими запросами.  request,  session, application, flow.  самые коротко живущие обьекты  живуь  о обьекте request самые долгоживущие  живут  пока живет приложени -Application scope.  Соотвественно сохраняйте свои формы  в том  обьекте которым  пользуетесь.
У обьектов  Application,request,session есть  пары  методов  для  работы с атрибутами: setAttribute("myAttr",  myObj ),  и getAttribute("myAttr").
Application  ctx= request.getContext.setAttribute("request", myLoveObject ());
Но сейчас  появились  CDI со своим  жизненым  циклом. Если  используете нормальный сервер j2ee , то лучше смотреть в сторону  CDI.